# ¿como agregar varias direcciones a un submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, bitbucket

muchachos, una pregunta casual, busque por todos lados pero no lo logre

tengo un repositorio(**repo1**)

**hago fetch(bitbucket)**

**hago cualquier cambio en archivos**

**hago push(bitbucket,  github, gitlab)**

hasta ahi todo bien, **me funciona perfectamente**, manejo **1 repositorio en 3 servidores diferentes**

ahora, hice lo mismo con otro repositorio(**repo2**), funciona bien al igual que el anterior 1 en 3

bien, hasta van entendiendo? perfecto

vamos a lo siguiente, **agregue como submodule repo2 en repo1**

osea que quedo:

```
-repo1(principal)
--repo2(submodule)
```

bien, ahora subo nuevamente los datos a los servidores

**hago push(bitbucket,  github, gitlab)**

funciona perfectamente, **se ve que es un modulo en los servidores**

bien, perdón por ser explicito, ahora vamos al problema que tengo

***bitbucket***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hago click en el submodulo **me lleva** hacia el repo2

.............................................

***github***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hago click en el submodulo **NO me lleva** hacia el repo2

.............................................

***gitlab***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando hago click en el submodulo **NO me lleva** hacia el repo2

entonces, vamos a la logica, agregue en repo1 el repo2 de la siguiente manera

```
git submodule add git@bitbucket.com:usuario/test-module.git submodulo
```

entonces, ahí ya le indico al repo1 que el repo2 esta en la siguiente dirección, es por eso que desde bitbucket si me lleva al repo2

bien, ahora la pregunta del millon

**¿COMO AGREGO OTRA DIRECCION EN EL MISMO SUBMODULE?**

intente de la siguiente manera

```
git submodule add git@github.com:usuario/test-module.git submodulo
git submodule add git@gitlab.com:usuario/test-module.git submodulo
```

pero no me permite hacerlo por que la carpeta ya existe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si borro la carpeta, estamos en la misma situación, por que solo me permite agregar 1 de 3 servidores

Comment: ya miraste esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818963/4717133 y esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035018/4717133

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso eres un crack! logre solucionar el problema, gracias por los links aportados :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias [@Francisco Núñez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/46896/francisco-n%C3%BA%C3%B1ez-todo-poderoso) , lo conseguí de la siguiente manera

mi archivo ".submodules" contiene

```
[submodule "submodulo"]
    path = submodulo
    url = git@bitbucket.org:usuario/test-module.git
```

solo quite la ruta del servidor

```
[submodule "submodulo"]
    path = submodulo
    url = ../test-module.git
```

[mas información sobre los submodulos relativos](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/Relative_submodules/)